# How to notify an ASP.NET Core MVC web app about an event occurred in a third party app

Tags: http, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a requirement wherein I need to perform certain action in my web application based on phone call receiving event that occurs in a third party application - Knowlarity SR calling app.

We are using Knowlarity Super Receptionist calling API to receive calls to a virtual number and then route those calls to call center Agents as per their availability. There is another web application we have built which call center agents uses to manage customers and orders. Agents login to this web application (web app in Azure) and places orders for customer who is calling over the phone from Knowlarity. Here the requirement is whenever Knowlarity routes the call to any agent and when the agent picks up the call, it should notify this action to web app (CRM) the web app should automatically redirect the same Agent to a specific page.

Please suggest a solution how I can listen to the call receiving event in Knowlarity and do some action(page redirection) on the web app side.

Thanks.

I tried writing an Api method in Web app which Konwlarity will call to send event notification with some information. Also tried implementing `HttpHandler` for this. Please suggest the correct approach for this. Remember that it is a Web app so multiple agents can login, they have their own session so how to handle this.

Comment: Is the Knowlarity contains any httphandler or it contains any trigger which could send the request to your web application?

Comment: They have some events that occurs on their end during call routing flow when call center person picks up the call